# Count Working Days between Dates starting from following day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a function that counts the working days between two dates. The problem is that it must only start counting from the day after the start date. If the start date is on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday) or a Friday then it must start counting from **Monday**.

At the moment, this code will count dates that start on weekends perfectly but if the start date is on a working day then it will count **1 day too many** as it also counts the **starting day** when it should **start from the following day**.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `BusinessDaysBetweenDates`(d1 DATE, d2 DATE) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE bDaysInPeriod INT;

    SET bDaysInPeriod=0;
    WHILE d1<=d2 DO
        IF DAYOFWEEK(d1) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN
            SET bDaysInPeriod=bDaysInPeriod+1;
        END IF;

        SET d1=d1+INTERVAL 1 day;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN bDaysInPeriod;
END
```

**Test Case:** Using a **start date** `01-01-2014` and **end date** `03-01-2014` it will produce `3 days` when it should produce `2 days`. If you fix it by simply minusing 1 day from the result then the **start date** of `04-01-2014` and **end date** of `08-01-2014` will produce `2 days` instead of `3 days`.

Comment: Do you want that strictly in function? That result could be get via SQL

Comment: I don't if this helps; it's just what showed up after a 7 second search on google... http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=91

Comment: @AlmaDo - but only if you use a uility table or some tedious UNION

Comment: @Strawberry there's some "universal" compact sequence builder for such cases. But - yes, it will use `UNION` (however, always same count of them no matter what is the desired interval)

Comment: Can you give an example of where the code fails?  Can you fix it just by adding 1 to the start date before the loop?

Comment: Please see the test case updated in the question above

Comment: Your function is flawed anyway because it does not incorporate holidays.  This is one of those situation where a calendar table comes in handy.  Ironically, I wrote a "business days between" query yesterday and it took a long time to get it right.  Too bad the RDBMS I was using does not allow us to write our own functions.  This would have been a good candidate.

Comment: Friends, we don't have to slag this guy  :-) Maybe the problem he's trying to solve is simpler than the one in http://www.dreamingincode.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to this problem seems workable.  It will be especially workable when you add a table of arbitrary holidays to your application.

I believe you have a simple off-by-one error in your computation. Try changing your logic to do this:

```
SET bDaysInPeriod=0;
SET d1=d1+INTERVAL 1 DAY;    /* start counting the day after start date */
WHILE d1<=d2 DO
    IF DAYOFWEEK(d1) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN
        SET bDaysInPeriod=bDaysInPeriod+1;
    END IF;
    SET d1=d1+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
END WHILE;
RETURN bDaysInPeriod;
```

Here are some potential test cases:

```
 start date  end date   returned value

   Mon         Tues        1
   Sun         Mon         1
   Fri         Mon         1
   Fri         Tues        2
   Sat         Sun         0
   Sat         Mon         1
   Sun         Tues        2
```

I think it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a day to the start day *before* calling the function.

If the start day is Friday, you'll get Saturday, which won't be counted, since it's not a workday. If the start day is Sunday, you'll end up with Monday, which will be the first day to be counted.

---

Or you could skip the function and do it in a query.

```
WITH days AS (
   SELECT TRUNC(:start_date) + LEVEL AS my_day
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY TRUNC(:start_date) + LEVEL <= TRUNC(:end_date)
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS workdays
FROM days
WHERE TO_CHAR(my_day, 'D') NOT IN ('1', '7');
```

The day numbers you need to exclude depend on the actual days you want to exclude and on you NLS settings, `NLS_TERRITORY` to be exact. Here, I assumed you want to exclude the weekend and have a setting where 1 = Sunday and 7 = Saturday.